# mapping a button into material ui-table's row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mapping

i am using data-table i have to define rows and columns like this (i use map to add the button into each row of data i get from outside)

```
const finalData = data.map(({id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, attorney, leadType, date}) => ({id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, attorney, leadType, date, action: <button>button</button>}))
const rows = finalData;

<DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
```

however in my row i dont get a button instead i get [object object] how can i fix this?

Comment: what result ```console.log(finalData)```?

Comment: yeah i cannot keep button element inside an object so how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are taking about `DataGrid from material-ui`, seems like you cannot do it simply using JSX as a key value while mapping your rows. You have to use something known as `renderCell()` to include the the custom JSX.

For instance,

You can use :-

```
{
    field: 'action',
    headerName: 'Action',
    renderCell: () => (
      <button>
        Content
      </button>
    ),
  },
```

as one of the column entries to render a separate Action column with your required button.

Refer the following for more info:-

https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rendering/#components

Comment: They're talking about [DataGrid](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/#overview)

Comment: Thanks for the info @NearHuscarl. I have updated the answer accordingly.